# : Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in D:\SUJON\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\class-http.php on line 1589 in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

why show Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds  exceeded in D:\SUJON\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\class-http.php on line 1589 in wordpress

Answer (score 0):

From the PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

set_time_limit
bool set_time_limit ( int $seconds )

Set the number of seconds a script is allowed to run. If this is reached, the script returns a fatal error. The default limit is 30 seconds or, if it exists, the max_execution_time value defined in the php.ini.